# Help with Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

How do I solve the following equation in terms of $p$ and $q$ if,

$$a^2 + b^2 - ab = p$$

And

$$2a^3 + 2b^3 -3ab(a+b) = - q$$

I tried lots of stuff, but I just can't see it, I end up with complicated equations. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: eliminate a from the first equation, substitute this into the second equation, and you will end up with an equation of 6th degree in b^2. Solving this results in a admittedly complicated but explicit expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is a start which will get you through in the end. Though whether this is the best way, I don't know.

Multiply the first equation by $a+b$ to obtain $$a^3+b^3=p(a+b)$$

Substitute this in the second to obtain $$(2p-3ab)(a+b)=-q$$

Square this $$(2p-3ab)^2(a+b)^2=q^2$$

Now notice that the first equation can be written $$(a+b)^2=p+3ab$$

So that $$(2p-3ab)^2(p+3ab)=q^2$$

This is a cubic in the unknown $ab$ (or $3ab$) and can be solved using standard methods. Once $ab$ is known $(a+b)^2=p+3ab$ will give $a+b$ and $a$ and $b$ will emerge from a quadratic. Then check which of the solutions solve the original equations.

There may be an easier way through.

Comment: Nice way to do it ! I started ... an arrived to a small nightmare !

Comment: Nice but is it not possible to write it only in terms of $p$ and $q$ ... Your solution is wonderful but your answer sadly has $a$ and $b$ :(

Comment: @William You get $ab$ and $a+b$ in terms of $p$ and $q$. Then you can solve for $a$ and $b$ using a quadratic - you do get them in terms of $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 0):

Not very pleasant, for sure, but you can consider the first equation and solve it for $a$ to get the two possible roots
$$a_1=\frac{1}{2} \left(b-\sqrt{4 p-3 b^2}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad a_2=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4 p-3 b^2}+b\right)$$

Replace in the second equation to get
$$3 b^2 \sqrt{4 p-3 b^2}-p \sqrt{4 p-3 b^2}+q=0$$
$$-3 b^2 \sqrt{4 p-3 b^2}+p \sqrt{4 p-3 b^2}+q=0$$
Let $x^2=4p-3b^2$ to end with cubic equations in $x$.

Comment: Could you explain the second step Sir? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @William. Take $a_1$ and plug it in the second equation to get the first of my equations. Take $a_2$ and plug it in the second equation to get the second of my equations.